# Fetch as Google: Differences between Googlebot and Visitor views

Tags: google-search-console, fetch-as-google

I have an AJAX-heavy website that I'm trying to get indexed properly in Google. When I use the "Fetch as Google" tool, all the content shows up in the "This is how a visitor to your website would have seen the page" view, but some content that is loaded via AJAX does not show up in the "This is how Googlebot saw the page" view.

I see a "Googlebot couldn't get all resources for this page. Here's a list:" message below, but the only entry in the list is an externally-hosted analytics script that doesn't impact what data the page displays.

I haven't been able to find documentation on the differences between the two views. I found a general description of how Google renders Javascript here (https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/rendering) but nothing in the article explains the differences I'm seeing, and I've tested the page on Chrome 41 and see the same thing as the "how a visitor to your website" screenshot.

I'm at a loss for how to debug this. My only hypothesis is that it has to do with the timing of when the AJAX content is loaded, because Google is rendering content created via javascript that runs on page load. How does Google decide when the page is "loaded" for the purposes of capturing the content?